# didBeginContact() called before contact occurred

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have two sprite nodes where I have made sure both `self.size` and the size of their respective physics bodies is the same, but I still get a very odd behavior like this:[image: Odd behaviour]

The photo is taken as the collision has been detected and i paused the scene. Why does this happen?

Here is the code for setting the different sizes:
Inside `init()` of my Player class (circular node):

```
 super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

then:

```
 self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/2, center: self.position)
```

Comment: What is the real size of an image when you open it in image editor ?

Comment: The problem turned out to be me specifying the property as = player.size.width/2 when initializing an object in didMoveToView(). Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Turn on physics visual representation in you `GameViewController.swift`, like this:

```
 skView.showsPhysics = true
```

`self.size` in your case probably referring to the scene. What you need is to set physics body's size like this:

```
yourNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: yourNode.size)
```

Also keep in mind that if you are altering node's anchor point,you may end up with unexpected results. Anchor point defines how texture is drawn relative to the node. It has no effect on node's physics body.

Comment: Thanks for the .showsPhysics method. really helped finding the issue. My issue seems to be the physics body of the circular node being too big. I'll update with the code I use.